# Why does nested directives Controller and Link functions trigger order depend on template and templateUrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling

I'm using AngularJs 1.4.8 and I noticed strange behaviour :

When you have 2 directives one inside of other :

```
angular.module('another-module', [])
            .directive('anotherModuleOuter', function () {
                return {
                    scope: {},
                    controller: function () {
                        console.log('another-module-outer - controller');
                    },
                    link: function () {
                        console.log('another-module-outer - link');
                    },
                    template: '<div>another-module-outer <div another-module-inner></div></div>'
                }
            })
            .directive('anotherModuleInner', function () {
                return {
                    scope: {},
                    controller: function () {
                        console.log('another-module-inner - controller');
                    },
                    link: function () {
                        console.log('another-module-inner - link');
                    },
                    template: '<div>another-module-inner</div>'
                }
            });
```

You'd get

```
another-module-outer - controller
another-module-inner - controller
another-module-inner - link
another-module-outer - link
```

Meaning that outer directive's controller will be called first and link function - last.

However, if you change inner's template :

```
template: '<div>another-module-inner</div>'
```

to templateUrl like :

```
templateUrl: 'anotherModuleInner.html'
```

loading order would also change (outer directive's link will be triggered before inner's controller):

```
another-module-outer - controller
another-module-outer - link
another-module-inner - controller
another-module-inner - link
```

Why does it work like this?

P.S/

I'm having a problem with events where inner directive registers $scope.$on() and outer fires $rootScope.$broadcast() but since inner function $on is registered after broadcast it doesn't catch anything. I'd be grateful if you suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is in the docs under [`$compile` for templateUrl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-)

> Because template loading is asynchronous the compiler will suspend
>   compilation of directives on that element for later when the template
>   has been resolved. In the meantime it will continue to compile and
>   link sibling and parent elements as though this element had not
>   contained any directives.

Comment: thanks, do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem with events? $timeout doesn't seem to help, as far as I understand I only waits for one digest cycle

Comment: You could maybe fire an event in the inner for when it completes to be picked up in the outer that then fires off its event. But unless you are passing data you might just need the one event.